# Dynamically disable the select field condition is if we change another select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="specific_content" value="2">
    <label for="test2" class="parent_row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="content_form[]">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
                <option value="category">Category</option>
                <option value="genre">Genre</option>
                <option value="cast">Cast</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="select-btn">
                <select name="content_type[]" multiple class="form-control">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control condition-section" name="conditions[]">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
                <option value="1">AND</option>
                <option value="2">OR</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).on('change', "select[name='conditions[]']",  function(e){ 
        if($(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != "Select" && $(this).val() != "") {

        var selectedCat = [];
        $("select[name='content_form[]']").each(function(e){   
            if($(this).val()) {
                selectedCat.push($(this).val()); 
            }                             
        }); 

        //alert(JSON.stringify(selectedCat));

        var row = '<label class="parent_row">';
        row += '<div class="col-md-4">';
        row += '<select class="form-control" name="content_form[]">';
        row += '<option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select</option>';

        var unselectedCatPresent = false;
        if(selectedCat.indexOf('category') == -1) {
            row += '<option value="category">Category</option>';
            unselectedCatPresent = true;
        }
        if(selectedCat.indexOf('genre') == -1) {
            row += '<option value="genre">Genre</option>';
            unselectedCatPresent = true;
        }
        if(selectedCat.indexOf('cast') == -1) {
            row += '<option value="cast">Cast</option>';
            unselectedCatPresent = true;
        }   

        row += '</select>';
        row += '</div>';
        row += '</label>';

        if(unselectedCatPresent) {
            $(this).closest('label.parent_row').after(row);  
        }            
    } else if($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).closest('label.parent_row').nextAll().remove();  
    }
});
```

The above is my HTML and jQuery code.

While changing the `AND/OR` dropdown, I am creating a new row having the all 3 select field and condition is there shouldn't be the first dropdown value.

That means if I already Category selected then I can't select Category again in the newly created section.
I want to disable the same drop down field if AND/OR selected.

Please look at the below image for more details.

[image]

As you can see in the above image there is two section having 3 drop down each. My requirement is that in the first section, if AND/OR selected, then we can't choose from first drop down (in image Category present). But We can choose from 2nd section (in image Genre present), as in the 3rd dropdown Select field is present AND/OR option not selected. Once we selected AND/OR, we need to make read only option for the first select field for that particular row. Could anyone please help me on this? Also, note dropdowns are coming dynamically.

Comment: There is a bit too much going on here to understand quickly.. Can you give a small working example to speed things up ? For a starter I made a JSFiddle but it's not much help... https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/853695/

Comment: Can I create a video and share to you?

Comment: maybe you can explain in some more clear steps what you want to happen.. From start to end..

Comment: After all this explanations it looks like the best way would be to drop all disabled and hidden attributes from the options. Firstly, they're not supported in all browsers, and secondly, a disabled option is not passed to a server, which might mess up the server-side validation because index 0 might have different meanings. For example: User never pick up a condition, but your server gets "AND" as a selected value, because the correct option is disabled, and the option 1 will be passed instead of the real selection.

Comment: @Teemu , Can we make read only option as in read only value will be goes to server.

Comment: @Pogrindis , We need to make read only the first dropdown value, if there is AND/OR selected in the 3rd dropdown

Comment: All of you please go through the below video link what is the problem coming and how I can manage this?
https://www.useloom.com/share/a6f17067cfd54b01bf0fb888afa5164a

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't want the same value to be selected in the first combo of newly created row of two combo...I would suggest that while generating the select field dynamically don't add options which are already selected in previous combos....For that you need to maintain the list of already selected values